# curl: (56) Failure when receiving data from the peer

Tags: linux, bash, curl

hello Im on shared hosting and I am able to ssh in and run the following command

```
 curl -O http://myurl.co.uk/customers/cron/invoices/gIsoaGANyWlJ
```

and it seems to work OK and gives the following output which looks pretty good to me

```
 % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
 0    14    0    14    0     0     35      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--    35
```

but Im running it from cron using a script called reoccuringinvoices.sh
The contents of the script is simply

```
#!/bin/bash

curl -O http://myurl.co.uk/customers/cron/invoices/gIsoaGANyWlJ
```

but when I run this version from cron it returns the following:

```
 % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  curl: (56) Failure when receiving data from the peer
```

To be honest Im totally confused and any help to start to understand whats happening would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Could you please show the cron entry you made? And please also show the output of `env` in a shell where the `curl` request works.

Comment: Is SELinux enabled? Do you run cron task from your user?

Answer (score -2):

Use wget instead curl

wget http://myurl.co.uk/customers/cron/invoices/gIsoaGANyWlJ

**Curl have permissions on write?**

Maybe create curl log

```
curl -O http://myurl.co.uk/customers/cron/invoices/gIsoaGANyWlJ 2>&1 | tee curl.log
```

Or change -O at -v and see log

```
curl -v http://myurl.co.uk/customers/cron/invoices/gIsoaGANyWlJ 2>&1 | tee curl.log
```